# Cloning the Existing Project in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the description of the situation:

- I have a reload Job that takes data
- the reload Job loads the new data every day in the morning in SQL Server Database
- When the new data is in the tables, the job processes 3 Cubes (Mgmt, Team, and Project cube)
- In regard to 3 cubes, 3 roles have been defined: Mgmt_Reader, Project_Reader, and Box_Reader, respectively.

Here is the request - department manager wants to "clone" the project for his department.
My question is - what would be smart to do:

- Maybe on the lower level in the reload Job include the data for the both departments.
- In the next phase no changes are made - when the reload job loads the Database on SQL Server
- Would than be possible to make another 3 Roles (6 overall) for the department manager? And would then be possible to make the corresponding restrictions, so that he can see only the data relevant to his department?
- If yes, I ask kindly for feedback, how I can do it?
- Or, do you know an approach that is more elegant, that the suggested one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered to create a "Department" dimension?

Comment: It seems that it is possible to solve it with an additionals roles and additional active idrectory groups. I have a dimension where different departments are listed. Now the big question is - where and how do I need to make and define the role.

Comment: I suppose that I need to do it in Management Studio by connecting to Analysis Services Project. Than I need to find Roles and add a new one. In "membership" tab I define access rights for User groups, in "Data sources" I select the corresponding database, in "Cubes" I Set Read access rights to the corresponding cube, in "Dimensions" I select all dimensions, and in "Dimension Data" (where supposedly I have to restrict the Department dimension) I get the following error: "Error retrieving children - The xyz object was not found. Parameter name: index". Can you help me with this please?